# Delete a key in a subarray

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-array like this:

```
 array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["Id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "Portugal"
        ["Country"]=>
        string(8) "Portugal"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "sometext"
        ["Type"]=>
        string(8) "sometext"
        [3]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["xptoabcdef"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["Id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "Portugal"
        ["Country"]=>
        string(8) "Portugal"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "sometext"
        ["Type"]=>
        string(8) "sometext"
        [3]=>
        string(2) "22"
        ["xptoabcdef"]=>
        string(2) "22"
      }
```

How can I delete the "Country" column from the array in the most simple way?

Comment: `foreach` (with reference) or `array_map`, and `unset` the appropriate key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something with [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map)

```
$new_array = array_map(function($v) {
    unset($v['Country']);
    return $v;
}, $old_array);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/67255).

Comment: Great job! thanks :) It would be great if you could add a simple explanation of the code.

Comment: @2Noob2Good: np mate, but I cannot write better explanation that is already on manual site: http://us2.php.net/array_map . Basically what array_map() does, it loops over all first elements of the given array (parameter `$v`). Then you modify that array `$v` by unseting some variable, and return it.

Comment: The explanation should be edited into the answer, not commented.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with a callback function to achieve this:

```
$array = array_map(function($elem) {
   unset($elem['Country']); 
   return $elem;
}, $array);
```

Or use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop and pass the value by reference, like so:

```
foreach ($array as $key => & $value) {
    unset($value['Country']);
}
```

[Demo!](https://eval.in/67263)

Answer (score 1):

To delete all instances of a key (or keys) in an array and its sub-arrays (no matter how deep):

```
print_r(deep_delete_keys($arr,'country'));

function deep_delete_keys($arr, $keys) {
    if (!is_array($keys)) $keys = array($keys);
    $filteredArr = array_diff_key( $arr, array_flip( $keys ) );
    foreach ($filteredArr as &$val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = deep_delete_keys($val, $keys);
        }
    }
    return $filteredArr;
}
```